# adding a new decorator for restframework viewset action decorator

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, decorator

I've a django viewset, to which I've added a functions with action decorator. I want to add  a custom decorator for this function.

```
    @action(
        methods=["post"],
        detail=True,
        permission_classes=[],
        url_path="rename-book",
        url_name="rename-book",
    )
    def rename_book(self, request, pk=None):
        book_instance = self.get_object()
        book_instance.name = request.data['name']
        book_instance.save()
        return Response({"message":"Done"})
```

I want to add a custom decorator for authentication and checking the user anonymity. Any idea on how to move forward?

Comment: only for this particular view method, or for entire view class?

Comment: only for this particular method.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using *decorator* you can use `permission_classes` like this:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
```

and

```
@action(
    methods=["post"],
    detail=True,
    permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated,],
    url_path="rename-book",
    url_name="rename-book",
)
def rename_book(self, request, pk=None):
    book_instance = self.get_object()
    book_instance.name = request.data['name']
    book_instance.save()
    return Response({"message":"Done"})
```

Comment: My authentication is for a specific set of users only. so I can't use IsAuthenticated.

Comment: you can write your [custom permission](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) instead of `IsAuthenticated`
@likhithlanka